# Dollar-cost-averaging interval based on decay of autocorrelation?

Tags: dollar-cost-averaging

I've read descriptions of DCA as buying more of something when it's cheap, and less when it's expensive.  In contrast, if you buy much of that thing all at once, you may be buying the whole load at a peak or trough price, i.e., you're either way worse off or way better off.  This means it's more of a gamble due to its uncertainty.  In a sense, with DCA, you end up buying at the temporally local average price.

As a conceptual toy problem, I pondered what would be a good frequency at which to make DCA purchases.  I haven't been able to see an intuitive answer over the years, but I'm wondering if this next idea might be a good rough guide.

The fluctuations in the price of a thing to buy has a slow and fast variations.  You'll never average out the slower fluctuations unless you intend to make DCA purchases forever.  Would it be a good idea to look at the autocorrelation of the price function in time, gauge the time interval that it takes to fall "relatively" flat, then choose a DCA purchase interval to be that time?  My thinking is that, with purchases made at that interval, the prices are uncorrelated, so you end up averaging out the faster fluctuations.

Comment: This is the Vanguard study on dollar cost averaging indicating if the money is going to be invested you should just invest it as a lump sum. https://personal.vanguard.com/pdf/s315.pdf What you're talking about is no different than any other form of market timing.

Comment: With DCA in uniform dollar amounts, *your* average price is *lower* than the temporal average price, because you buy more when the price is lower.

Comment: The Vanguard article refers to DCA as *a form* of market timing, which is quite different from saying that it is no different from any other form of market timing. I believe that it depends on how loosely one defines market timing. I see it as a day trader trying to divine when to buy/sell based on knowledge/news of what is going on in the world, including based on emotion. Making regular fixed transactions seems the very opposite of that, so to me, it's a stretch to call it market timing.

Comment: I would have preferred if the article ground out a probability distribution of the difference in outcome between the different strategies. That would take into account the deepness of the difference, and not just how often one beats the other. In any case, the intuition is described as obvious up front for up-trending markets.  For down-trending markets, lump-sum at the *end* of the DCA period would beat the DCA plan. Admittedly, markets tend to trend up.  I guess I should have described the fact that I was trying to attenuate the uncertainty rather than beat lump sum in an up-trend.

Comment: I said what YOU are talking about is no different than market timing, because you are adding a decision algorithm.  Over the full history of the market it has been in an uptrend.

Comment: And what I was talking about was DCA, and I provided reasons why one might not consider it to be market timing. The word "market" seems to be used losely in your last comment. The market of 8 track tapes definitely hasn't been trending upward since the beginning of time, so I suspect that you mean specifically stock markets?

Comment: Here's another example of where the "market" might not be so simple.  Say you drawing from a high risk, high reward instrument into a lower risk,lower reward instrument.  You might use DCA to average out some of the high frequency variation and reduce the uncertainty.  So not every situation falls under the very specific conditions of the report.

Answer (score 1):

Market prices approximate Brownian motion, which has no intrinsic time scale (it is self-similar, with fluctuations on *all* time scales). The autocorrelation of price *never* falls off because the expectation value of the price at any future time is tied to the current price (modulo interest, dividends, etc.) -- a [martingale](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory))-like process.

Comment: I spent the evening reviewing Martingale processes. Great for investments, but doesn't the scale-less fluctuations translate into the fact that the "noise" is both slow and fast?  I was simply trying to avoid the greater uncertainty due to noise.  With DCA over a finite period, I can't beat slow noise, but I can avoid the uncertainty from fast noise.  Given that as the goal, it seems that choosing a DCA purchase interval averages out the fast noise in the frequencies above 1/(interval), leaving the uncertainty from the slow noise.

Comment: The disturbing thing is that I can't use ACF die-out period to estimate the DCA purchase interval, if it never falls off.  I haven't looked at how ACFs look when there is a gross trend. I get traumatic flashbacks of reading about time series with unit roots and such. Though in time series (which I've never actually done), we remove the trend and periodic pieces to leave only the stationary noise. It assumes that the nonrandom components are recognizable, for removal.

Comment: @user2153235 I suspect what's being said is that there will be _slow_ noise, _fast_ noise, and _all speeds in between_ noise. If so, you can't _simply_ separate out the slow from the fast... it's may be there's a way to apply the equivalent of a "low pass filter", to _reduce_ the effects of fast noise, but I've no idea whether what you're proposing would do this.

Comment: Yes, the fast and slow noise was simpler than saying a noise spectrum.  And temporal averaging is just low pass filtering.  So I guess the question has more to do with choosing the sample interval, and it assumed that the ACF decayed, which means that the noise bandwidth is approxiimately the inverse of the decay interval (which itself is eyeballed).  If the sample interval was wide enough, the samples being averaged would be relatively uncorrelated, thus filtering away the high frequency noise.  But you would sitll be at the mercy of the temporally local variation.

Comment: Which still reduces the uncertainty.  While this was the motive for the question, I guess it is a secondary effect of DCA.

Answer (score 0):

**Serial correlation and stock returns**

No, it does not make sense. Stock prices do not have reliable serial correlation at frequencies that will matter to you, so you will not be able to find a frequency at which movements tend to cancel each other out going forward.

Any serial correlation happening with actionable frequency would imply a trading pattern that someone could use to make a ton of money. Doing so would dampen the pattern out. Even though your intent is not to "beat the market," the type of pattern you are looking for would lend itself to this.

It is easy to find serial correlation and other patterns in any given historical sample, but you will find that when you use them out-of-sample, whether as a statistical arbitrage rule or as an "improvement" to a rule like DCA, it will not reliably give you the results you are seeking. In other words, if you implement DCA at a given frequency, you will find that it will outperform other frequencies only according to chance, despite any optimization you did to choose that frequency.

Nanoman's answer says this same thing, but some of the consequences of that answer may not have been obvious.

**Dollar Cost Averaging**

Another point: DCA reduces risk relative to an up-front investment only because your money spends less time invested. Its reduction in expected return is proportional to the reduction in risk. The idea that 'buying more when cheap' outperforms 'buying it all up front' in a risk-adjusted sense is incorrect. There's no theoretical advantage to DCA over simply making a proportionally smaller investment up front and leaving it. The reason DCA is relevant to our world is that it matches what people do when they make monthly investments out of their paycheck.

Best not to take timing advice from anyone who suggests that DCA has any theoretical advantage over all-at-once investment. I say this knowing full well that most retail-level financial advisors and virtually all internet warriors do exactly this.

Comment: Hi, farnsy, not sure if I was sufficiently clear about this, but I'm
not trying to capitalize on correlations. I'm trying to determine how
the spacing of purchases that minimize correlations, at least as
indicated by the autocorrelation function. Perhaps the use of the term
*DCA* was misleading, as it implies trying to beat upfront lump sum?

Comment: In contrast, I'm looking at a more general buying situation, e.g.,
perhaps even buying products rather than investments, or transferring
funds between investments. The aim is to avoid the uncerntainty in
fluctations and realize the local average. I'm wondering if we might be
speaking about different problems.

Comment: For a given asset, there is a tradeoff between volatility/risk and expected return. You have described your problem in terms of minimizing the volatility/risk caused by purchase timing. This is equivalent to getting a better expected return for a given volatility--they require the same information. Neither is possible unless there is a consistent/persistent pattern in returns, which there is not.

Comment: You will certainly reduce your uncertainty and realize the local average by using any kind of trading pattern that buys over time instead of at once. But you will lose the associated expected return. Statistically this is no better than just buying up front, in a lesser amount.

Comment: Yes, but spacing the purchases in time is not arbitrary.  One has to choose the spacing to avoid the high frequency fluctuations, though you will still be subjected to the low frequency. If spacing is too small, you avoid most of neither.  As for expected returns, I'm less concerned about that if I'm timing (say) consumer product purchases or transferring funds between investment vehicles rather than having cash sit in a 0-return account. I don't treat expected returns as the only consideration, otherwise I'd do a lump sum upfront purchase of something with very high risk and return.

Comment: Your distinction between short and long horizon fluctuations sounds arbitrary to me. There is no natural distinction as pointed out in the other answer. I think what everyone is trying to say here is that the objectives you have stated do not make sense in an investing context. There is no frequency of DCA that is "better" than others in the sense that you will be better off if you follow it. In finance, "better off" means improvement in E(R) or risk. No frequency of DCA can take you outside the frontier defined by a static, up front, allocation except by chance.

Comment: My use of short and long fluctuations is just a stand-in for saying that the randomness has a power spectrum that is the Fourier Transform of the ACF.  But it's not necessary to get into that dense terminology because the ideas are very intuitive.  That doesn't mean that those concepts are just made up.  The reason why I keep returning to this is because the advice provided keep referring to DCA in an investment context, and I've repeatedly try to correct that.  Not trying to be difficult, but it has to make mathematical sense.

Comment: With respect, your comments persistently don't make sense. Your question as written is clearly about investments--any question not about investments is not on topic in this place. You have had very good and correct answers, which apply to anything you could buy and sell with any reasonable degree of liquidity. Everything you have mentioned that I have seen is a form of DCA and reduces both your expected return and your risk and is, in expectation, equivalent to a smaller up-front investment. Your search for an optimal DCA frequency is folly as has been explained multiple times here.

Comment: With respect, I disagree that everything I mentioned is a from of DCA, as I already mentioned quite a number of times how it differs.  I also suggested in the past that mentioning DCA could have confused the question and I tried to clarify this.  Regarding the comment that this forum is about liquid investments, one of the differences from the archetypal DCA problem is that it might also apply to transfers between investments, where the base option is not to let the funds sit in a 0 return alternative.  Finally, isn't this group about more than just investment, but also money?